# How to save ternary operator as a value on JavaScript (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, ternary

I try code to create method in Node.js (Express). I want to using ternary operator for return data and this following code is work perfectly.

```
const update = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params
    const { name, price } = req.body

    if (!(name && price)) {
      !name ? 
      res.status(409).json({
        status: res.statusCode,
        message: "Name must not empty!"
      }) : 
      
      res.status(409).json({
         status: res.statusCode,
         message: "Price must not empty!"
      })

    } else {
      await Product.update({ name: name, price: price}, {
        where: {
          ...
        }
      })
    }
  
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

But, can I assigned / save ternary operator as a variable for simple code?

I try to following code to save as a variable but still not working.

```
const x = !name ? "Name" : "Price"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after few minutes later and research from internet. I get solution from [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/javascript-by-example-use-of-the-ternary-operator-2037394).

```
const update = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params
    const { name, price } = req.body

    if (!(name && price)) {
      const x = (!name) ? "Name" : "Price"
      res.status(409).json({
        status: res.statusCode,
        message: `${x} must not empty!`
      })
      
    } else {
      await Product.update({ name: name, price: price}, {
        where: {
          ...
        }
      })
    }
  
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

First, I assign Name/Price to variable using ternary-operator and using template literals.

In my opinion, this following code is more simple than before.